# Get Average from two JSON Arrays

Tags: python

I have two json feeds which I combined into one file. Events and Users.  I need to get the average age from users.json to determine the average age of all distinct users who visited the home page (events.json).

Sample JSON Feed Events:

```
  "events": [
    {
      "name": "Added item to cart",
      "timestamp": 1422119921,
      "user_id": "5a5598f2-f7db-420e-9b8e-52a9ad694bc1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Visited product page",
      "timestamp": 1409554014,
      "user_id": "4683c9b6-3c8b-4215-a401-a9bbfde833ee"
    }
```

Sample Users Feed:

```
      "age": 27,
      "gender": "F",
      "device": "android"
    },
    "712ae3b5-fbf0-4d83-9324-adc06af77d3a": {
      "age": 34,
      "gender": "F",
      "device": "android"
    },
```

I'm new to python and I believe I am on the right track with the below but not sure where to go next. Any additional help would be appreciated.

```
import json 
  
# Opening JSON file 
with open('combined.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
  
    # for reading nested data [0] represents 
    # the index value of the list 
    print(data['events'][0]) 
    print(data['users'][0])
      
    # for printing the key-value pair of 
    # nested dictionary for looop can be used 
    print("\nPrinting nested dicitonary as a key-value pair\n") 
    for i in data['events']: 
        print("Name:", i['name'])
  for i in data ['users']:
        print ("Age:", i['age'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, just add up all the ages and divide by the number of users. This is one way to do that:

```
import json 

# Opening JSON file 
with open('combined.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
 
    total_age = 0
    counter = 0
    for k, v in json.load(data['users']).items():
        # Add all the ages
        total_age += v['age']
        counter += 1
    
    print(total_age / counter)
```

Comment: Hmm.  I'm getting an error when running the above: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 45, in <module>
    total_age += user['age']
KeyError: 'age'